# base64 encoded image not working in the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

Here i did multiple file images with base64 conversion , everything working fine , for my requirement user select the multiple images and click the submit button means i have to take the values(file) and converted to base64 encoded string,here when select image that time it will working fine but going submit the button i am getting undefined how to solve this error

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=property_images]").change(function() {
      var imgBase64Arr = [];
      var files = this.files;
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
          var FR = new FileReader();
          FR.onload = function(e) {
     
   var res = e.target.result ;
   var arr1 = res.split(",");
   var property_image = arr1[1] ;
            imgBase64Arr.push( property_image);//adding base64 value to array

            if(i === files.length -1)//after all files are porcessed
              myFunction(imgBase64Arr)
          };
          FR.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        })(i);
      }

    });
   
});

function myFunction(imgBase64Arr){
     console.log(imgBase64Arr);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="property_images" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Um you call myFunction without passing in anything! imgBase64Arr is undefined because it is undefined. Second when you do correct it, imgBase64Arr is defined in the change method so it is not assessable outside it.

Comment: You are not providing any argument into the function:`myFunction()`. When doing `console.log(imgBase64Arr);` `imgBase64Arr` is undefined.

Comment: while onchange the image i am pass like this myFunction(imgBase64Arr);

Comment: How to solve this issue any one please make fiddle answer

Answer (score 0):

When press submit button you call "myFunction" without passing anything..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imgBase64Arr = [];
    $("input[name=uploadBtn]").click(function(){
       console.log(imgBase64Arr);
    });
    $("input[name=property_images]").change(function() {
      imgBase64Arr = [];
      var files = this.files;
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
          var FR = new FileReader();
          FR.onload = function(e) {
     
   var res = e.target.result ;
   var arr1 = res.split(",");
   var property_image = arr1[1] ;
            imgBase64Arr.push( property_image);//adding base64 value to array

            if(i === files.length -1)//after all files are porcessed
              myFunction(imgBase64Arr)
          };
          FR.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        })(i);
      }

    });


   
});

function myFunction(imgBase64Arr){
     console.log(imgBase64Arr);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="property_images" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="button" name="uploadBtn" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your imgBase64Arr variable is not globally defined. Please defined it globally.